# Qt5/c++ generating 'Corrupted shared library list' error during debug

Tags: c++, qt, gdb, corruption, qsqldatabase

I have a Qt5/C++ app which appears to be working fine, but when running in debug mode (GDB), this error pops up on the QT Creator console (stderr) - OCCASIONALLY!:

```
Corrupted shared library list: 0x7fffe8008e90 != 0x751e50
```

I can't find any reference to the cause, and I can't figure out what is triggering it (other that something to do with using a QLinkedList.)  I tried switching to a QVector but sometimes the same error pops up.

What is this and how do I fix it?  Valgrind says no memory corruption...so is this a false reporting issue?  Or am I doing something wrong.

---

I've traced the above error to the last line (line 4) below.

```
Settings *programSettings =  Settings::instance();
QString driver=programSettings->database_driver();
driver="QMYSQL";  // Override for testing
m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(driver);
```

This makes no sense to me...can someone explain why the QSqlDatabase::addDatabase line causes corruption?  As well, why does the error ONLY appear when debugging...but not when running without gdb?

Comment: I don't think that Valgrind is guaranteed to catch all categories of errors. (For example, out of the box, it doesn't catch array overruns on the stack.) I don't know if it could be missing an error that causes this message or not.

Comment: Yes - running on Linux 64 bit Fedora 20.  I have Qt Creator's debug mode set (so all debug options should be enabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the number of views there seem to be a lot of people with this issue.  We pared the code down to a simple example and then reproduced the problem.  The source of the problem is not user code, but Qt Creator itself.  We can't go much further - just put up with it until a Qt Creator fix comes along.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're writing over memory that doesn't belong to yourself. It looks like you're dereferencing a pointer that has an uninitialized value. Compile your application with all warnings enabled, and make sure you understand all of the warnings. After that you may need to start a code audit, after you minimize the code of course.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error when stepping through the code with the debugger.  Is there a way to assert (or something similar) a valid pointer and have my code stop if invalid?

Comment: No, there isn't a way to assert such a thing, unfortunately. You probably can't reproduce while stepping through because the code (such as the event loop) runs many times per second...

Comment: After much debugging and creating sample code, this seems to be a Qt Creator issue.

Comment: @GenerationDSystems So, you say that if you run under standalone gdb, it doesn't happen, but through Qt Creator, it does? Does it also happen when running under lldb?